# PHP Swift Mailer attach FPDF Problems

Tags: php, email, attachment, fpdf, swiftmailer

I am having some issues with trying to get SwiftMailer to attach a file I have created with FPDF.  Basically I have a page called createPDF.php that is dynamically generated based on the ID number in the URL.  This page is set to output the PDF inline using $pdf->Output("filename.pdf",I);.  What I want to do is to be able to attach this file to an email using SwiftMailer from another page simply by calling my createPDF.php?id=xxx link.

From the PHP page where I want to send the email from, everything works, except the attachment.  It attaches something, but not what I want and it is not viewable in a PDF viewer on my local machine.  The line specific to the attaching the file is:

->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('createPDF.php?id=xxxx'))

This does not work, but surely, it must be possible without saving the file on my web server by FPDF.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I just figured this out.

Basically I made a new PHP file with the bulk of my createPDF.php file as a function and simply passed in two variables into the function as my $id and an $output variable.  $output is simply the way that FPDF outputs the file — inline, etc...  I then set the function to return the output of the FPDF.  In my createPDF.php file I simply call my function passing in $id and 'I' as the variables so it displays the correct PDF inline in the browser.

In my sendEmail function I simply pass in $id and 'S' and set it to a variable $content, which I pass into SwiftMailer as an attachment.

Works great.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is Swiftmailer gets the file contents, it does not execute your php file. So the contents of your PDF will the code that is in createPDF.php.

why cant you safe the file first? You should be able to safe it and delete it when your email is sent.

```
 <?php 
 $id = "xxx";
 $fileName = "tmp/".sha1(time()+mt_rand(0,99999999));
 include "createPDF.php"; //saves it to $fileName
 ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromFile( $fileName )->setFilename('blaha.pdf'));
 unlink($fileName);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your code correctly.  It is not working for me, I do not see where you specify the $id variable that would be in the createPDF.php?id=xxx URL.  

If I could save the createPDF.php?id=xxx file temporarily or something based on the ID variable, dynamically — the ID would need to change based on which PDF I need to send.  Then after the email is sent, delete this temporary file.  If I could do that, then that would work.

Also note, I am sending the email from a different file on my server.  The sendemail.php is in a different folder.  createPDF.php is in the / folder.

Comment: You should edit your createPDF.php to not set the id from $_GET, but just use $id, and make sure it saves to $filename.

Comment: I did that, and it still did not work.  I got more errors in my code.  Could you show me an example of how I would format the createPDF.php page and my other function (in another page) to send the email?  I basically have it set up in a function like sendEmail() in another PHP file.

I still want to be able to have createPDF.php be able to display the PDF inline if someone clicks on the link from their profile.

So I have:
createPDF.php
another PHP file with function sendEmail(){}